# Maximum with different calculation order

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have a sequence of $n$ numbers and $n-1$ operators (+ or -), where the order of the numbers and the operators are fixed. For example 5-2-1+3. By different parentheses, you get different values. For example (5 - 2)-1+3 = 5, 5-(2-1)+3=7, (5 - 2)-(1+3) = -1, and so on.
For example, the maximum of the sequence $4+3-2$ is $4+(3-2) = 5$.

I am interested in the maximum that such a sequence can have with proper parentheses. But I don't see any pattern and method how this can be determined efficiently ?

Comment: The question is not very clear for me. What is the exact problem? That you want to maximize such a difference? It's easy to create arbitrarily large numbers. For example, consider
$$
0 -0 + 1000 = 1000
$$
and you can put parentheses to make
$$
0 - (0+1000) = -1000
$$
And so the difference is 2000. Just multiply these numbers by any factor ...

Comment: @MattiP. I added another example. I hope this helps and make my question clear.